# Pandas .resample giving two different results

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to resample daily stock prices into monthly percentage returns. For such I have used two different approaches to pandas **.resample**, but it is giving me different results when it should not. What could be the issue?

First function:

```
mtl_ret = prices.pct_change().resample('M').agg(lambda x: (x+1).prod()-1)
```

Second function:

```
pricesM = prices.resample('M').last()
mtl_ret = pricesM.pct_change()
```

P.D.: The first function takes a long long time to process while the second one gives the results back in just a few seconds.

Comment: The operations are not commutative... In the first case, you compute the `pct_change` on all values then `resample`. In the second case, you take the last value for each month and compute the `pct_change`.

Comment: So which one best fits my initial purpose of transforming daily prices into monthly returns?

Comment: But month-to-month returns are calculated by using the last closing price of each month right? So why .mean() ?

Comment: Yes you are right so your second method is probably the one you need.